# React/Redux AG Grid not loading data

Tags: reactjs, redux, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I have a React app that uses Redux for the state management.

I am looking to integrate AG-Grid for displaying a nice grid of data, but when I try to set the `rowData` to the state for the data it returns no rows.

BookingList.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchBookings } from '../../actions';
import { AgGridReact } from 'ag-grid-react';
import 'ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.css';
import 'ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-balham.css';

class BookingList extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchBookings();
  }
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      columnDefs: [
        {
          headerName: 'First Name',
          field: 'firstName'
        },
        {
          headerName: 'Last Name',
          field: 'lastName'
        },
        {
          headerName: 'Email',
          field: 'emailAddress'
        },
        {
          headerName: 'Address',
          field: 'address'
        },
        {
          headerName: 'Market Date',
          field: 'marketDate'
        },
        {
          headerName: 'Stall Type',
          field: 'stallType'
        }
      ],
      rowData: [this.props.bookings]
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="ag-theme-balham">
        <AgGridReact
          columnDefs={this.state.columnDefs}
          rowData={this.state.rowData}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps({ bookings }) {
  return { bookings };
}
export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { fetchBookings }
)(BookingList);
```

The `fetchBookings` does work and populates data if I use a Material Design Card layout rather than AG-Grid so I now that part is working correctly.

Comment: There is no need to put either of those things in state, avoid state unless necessary (i.e. some use cases when mutating the data)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use `this` inside the constructor to address `props`:

Change to:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      columnDefs: [
        {
          headerName: 'First Name',
          field: 'firstName'
        },
        {
          headerName: 'Last Name',
          field: 'lastName'
        },
        {
          headerName: 'Email',
          field: 'emailAddress'
        },
        {
          headerName: 'Address',
          field: 'address'
        },
        {
          headerName: 'Market Date',
          field: 'marketDate'
        },
        {
          headerName: 'Stall Type',
          field: 'stallType'
        }
      ],
      rowData: props.bookings // assuming bookings is an array already
    };
  }
```

However, if you are connecting with redux it might be better to just use `props` and keep the `rowData` out of state:

```
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="ag-theme-balham">
        <AgGridReact
          columnDefs={this.state.columnDefs}
          rowData={this.props.bookings}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: That just gives an empty grid, but the state is there and is being populated with the reutn from the `fetchBookings` action

Comment: That got it! Thank you! It is an array of JSON objects, returned from an Express API

Comment: You can actually use `this` so long as `super(props)` was called first

Comment: @Dominic true, but don't you think it is confusing to use both?

Comment: Yeah sure I would use props directly but just saying ;)